# How to add shortcut for create unit test method

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

The environment is **Visual Studio Community 2022**, now I can add test by right click the method and select the **Create Unit Tests**

[image]

But there is no shortcut for it is possiable to set shortcut for this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question (without adding "Update" or "Edit" or anything else) so that your question is coherent from the start. If you can do so without all the screenshots, so much the better (remember that not everyone can see, and search engines won't capture the text in the image).

Comment: Can't you find the command in keyboard settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Visual Studio Community 2022**,select **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard**, search **EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.CreateUnitTests** then set shortcut and assign (for me I use Ctrl+T, Ctrl+T)
[image]

After that you will get it like below

[image]