# How to change Visual Studio Create Unit Tests default test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In **Visual Studio Community 2022** I can right click on method then select **Create Unit Tests** then it will pop out a window like below

[image]

I can select my test project or create a **New Test Project**, but the default value of it is always
**New Test Project**. How to change the default setting from **New Test Project** to my own test project?

Comment: VS does not have the function of setting this default value, you can go to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home) for feedback. If you want to perform unit testing quickly, you can also set shortcut keys.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT Thank you. About the shortcut did you mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75091409/how-to-add-shortcut-for-create-unit-test-method ? Or others way?

Comment: Yes, your steps are exactly correct. I originally wanted to get back to you about the shortcut key post, but later I found out that you had already written it.

Comment: I try that for a while and found how to set it. At first, I don't know which one is for unit test

Comment: Hi, can you share your specific steps?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT Reference this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75091409/how-to-add-shortcut-for-create-unit-test-method after click **Create Unit Test** the modal will popout